# can I reinstall npm in a angular project to fix it?

Tags: angular, npm

I have an angular 9 project. I have installed different libraries on it and after installing ngx-gallery and some issues for Rendere2 and etc, I edited some file in node-Module/angular/core like core.d.ts. I am very new to angular. now my project does not running, then I tried to delete node_module to install it again but I couldn't.
I wanna know Do I have any chance to fix all these with reinstalling npm or not. 
Thanks so much

update:I attached an image of errors that I have now.
[image]

Comment: BTW, in Angular 9 is definity deprecated Renderer is favor Renderer2 -so replace your Renderer by Renderer2 in your code-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could uninstall the specific package by running `npm uninstall <package>`, and then reinstall it again (`npm install <package>`).

Since you've already deleted all packages (if I got it right) and if all the packages that you used are saved in `package.json`, then you should just run `npm install` and it will reinstall all of the dependencies over there.

Comment: I think you can, try `npm uninstall @angular/core`. Then install it again `npm install -s @angular/core`

Comment: I did it but it gives same error in "node_modules/@angular/common/common.d.ts" and in " node_modules/@angular/core/core.d.ts"

Comment: Try doing the same for each package that got an effected by the change and has errors. `npm uninstall @angular/common` and then install it again.

Comment: If all of the dependencies were saved in package.json I would recommend deleting node_modules and `npm install` to reinstall all.

Comment: I reinstall @angular/common and removed bootstrap/dropdown module, it works now. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You would need to provide some more information about the file you modified that is causing issues, as I'm not clear what error you are getting. If you are asking if you can retain the content of the projects folder while reinstalling dependencies, just run `npm install` from within the directory.